# C++ SDL texture Error Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, image, textures, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to run this code but it keeps giving me an error.
I copyed SDL2_image.lib in the debug folder but in vain.
I'm at the beggining of programming so please be patient.

Errors: 
Error   1   error C3861: 'IMG_LoadTexture': identifier not found
Error   2   IntelliSense: identifier "IMG_LoadTexture" is undefined

```
#include<SDL/SDL.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
bool quit = false;

//*Initializing Window;
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Test", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

//*If game Crushes;
if (window == NULL)
{
    cout << "The game window is not working";
}

//*Creating Update Function
SDL_Renderer* render = NULL;
render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
SDL_Event* mainEvent = new SDL_Event();
//*End Update Function

//*Adding Textures;
SDL_Texture* grass_image = NULL;
grass_image = IMG_LoadTexture(render, "grass.bmp");

//*Creating a Sprite;
SDL_Rect grass_rect;
grass_rect.x = 10;
grass_rect.y = 50;
grass_rect.w = 250;
grass_rect.h = 250;



//*Content Of the Window;
while (!quit && mainEvent->type!=SDL_QUIT)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
    SDL_RenderClear(render);
    SDL_RenderCopy(render, grass_image, NULL, &grass_rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(render);
}
//*End Window Content

//*Memory Cleaning
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
delete mainEvent;
//*End Memory Cleaning

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have to include the `SDL_image` header too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to include the header that contains the declaration of `IMG_LoadTexture()`:

```
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
```

It's a separate extension library for SDL, and besides including that header, you'll also need to link that library with your project.

Comment: In addition to that they will need to initialize the library with `IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG|IMG_INIT_PNG|IMG_INIT_TIF)`
Note that you don't require SDL_image for bitmaps (I don't think SDL_image even supports bitmaps)

Comment: @Zammalad THX for the additional info. I'm way no expert in SDL, just scibbled that together, based on some fairly simple google research. Feel free to edit the answer and add this info. (gave my answer to the community wiki now)